# What Windows CE netbook supports .NET Compact framework?

Tags: netbook, windows-mobile, windows-ce

For reasons of curiousity and bloodymindedness I have decided to buy a Windows Mobile netbook, [like this one:](http://www.maplin.co.uk/module.aspx?moduleno=257308)

[image]

Theoretically it should [support the .NET Compact framework:](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9655156b-356b-4a2c-857c-e62f50ae9a55&displaylang=en)

Can anyone advise whether Windows CE 5 on this or similar netbooks could run the .NET Compact Framework 2.0 and/or whether I should wait for a newer version of Windows Mobile to be available on small netbooks?

Please don't tell me that I should get a bigger/real Windows netbook or a Linux netbook. I already have a 10" Windows 7 netbook and a 7" Debian netbook. I just buy cheap netbooks as a hobby.

But if you know of other cheap ~100 Euro netbooks running interesting operating systems, please point me to a store. Thank you.

Update: a better CE netbook:

[QBook 7" Portable](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Portable-Internet-Netbook-Notebook-Laptop/dp/B0034HQE7O/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&qid=1266232264&sr=8-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer.

According to the [Microsoft Windows CE Web site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms905330.aspx) Windows CE 5.0 supports the .NET Compact Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2:

***The .NET Compact Framework
Windows CE 5.0 adds the .NET Compact Framework Service Pack 2 functionality.***

Windows CE 6.0 also supports .NET Compact out of the box as [per the Windows CE 6.0 Web site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windowsembedded/ce/dd630616.aspx):

***Write native or managed code by choosing your preferred Microsoft development technology -- Win32, MFC, or the .NET Compact Framework (C#, VB).***